# Remove specific rows from data frame conditional on caseid and year

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

I'm a beginner in R, so please be gentle :)

I have a dataframe of the following form:

```
sampleData <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,2,2,3,4,4), 
                     year = c(2010, 2014, 2010, 2014, 2010, 2010, 2014))

sampleData
    id year
  1  1 2010
  2  1 2014
  3  2 2010
  4  2 2014
  5  3 2010
  6  4 2010
  7  4 2014
```

I want to exclude every id, which does not have both years.

In this case: id "3" only has year "2010".

Therefore I want to conditionally remove ids, which do not have another row with the missing year.

I hope you guys can understand what I'm looking for :(

thank you in advance!

Comment: `library(dplyr); df %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(n() >= 2)`

Comment: is it enough to check for (at least) two rows per id or do you need to check that both "2010" and "2014" are present per id?

Answer (score 2):

We can use `ave` and check number of rows for each `id` and select only those rows with `length` as 2.

```
sampleData[ave(sampleData$year, sampleData$id, FUN = length) == 2, ]

#  id year
#1  1 2010
#2  1 2014
#3  2 2010
#4  2 2014
#6  4 2010
#7  4 2014
```

---

In case if we want to check whether both "2010" and "2014" appear at least once per id we can do

```
sampleData[as.logical(ave(sampleData$year, sampleData$id, FUN = function(x)
                                            any(2014 %in% x) & any(2010 %in% x))), ]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sampleData <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,2,2,3,4,4), 
                     year = c(2010, 2014, 2010, 2014, 2010, 2010, 2014))
```

First you count :

```
library(plyr)
countBy     <- ddply(unique(sampleData), 
              .(id),
              summarise, 
              occurence = length(year) ,
              .parallel = F )
```

Then you subset

```
sampleData[sampleData$id %in% countBy$id[countBy$occurence > 1],]
```

Comment: I add the unique() function  to ensure no redundancy of same row.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `data.table`

```
library("data.table")
sampleData <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,2,2,3,4,4), year = c(2010, 2014, 2010, 2014, 2010, 2010, 2014))
setDT(sampleData)
sampleData[, `:=`(n, .N), by=id][n==2]
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to make your check more explicit, i.e. not just relying on two rows per id but checking whether both "2010" and "2014" appear at least once per id, you can do something like this in base R:

```
x <- table(sampleData$id, sampleData$year) > 0
x
#    2010  2014
#  1 TRUE  TRUE
#  2 TRUE  TRUE
#  3 TRUE FALSE
#  4 TRUE  TRUE

ids_to_keep <- row.names(x)[rowSums(x[,c("2010", "2014")]) == 2]
ids_to_keep
#[1] "1" "2" "4"

sampleData[sampleData$id %in% ids_to_keep,]
#  id year
#1  1 2010
#2  1 2014
#3  2 2010
#4  2 2014
#6  4 2010
#7  4 2014
```

This approach is longer than others but it's also more robust, for example if you can have multiple occurences of the same year per id, then some other approaches may fail or, if you can have other years (not just 2010 and 2014) some other approaches may also fail if they only rely on checking number of occurences per id.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a nice dplyr solution:

```
# create the sample dataset
sampleData <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,2,2,3,4,4), 
                         year = c(2010, 2014, 2010, 2014, 2010, 2010, 2014))

# load dplyr library
library(dplyr)

# take the sample dateset
sampleData %>%
        # group by id - thus the function within filter will be evaluated for each id
        group_by(id) %>%
        # filter only ids which were recorded in two separate years
        filter(length(unique(year)) == 2)
```